# EJB3/JPA entity with an aggregated attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, entity-relationship

I wanted to know if there is a way to get in a One2Many relationship a field of the One side that is an aggregate of the Many side.

Let's take the following example:

```
@Entity
public class A {
 @Id
 private Long id;
 @OneToMany (mappedBy="parentA")
 private Collection<B> allBs;

 // Here I don't know how to Map the latest B by date
 private B latestB;
    // Acceptable would be to have : private Date latestBDate;
}

@Entity
public class B {
 @Id
 private Long id;
 private Date date;
 @ManyToOne (targetEntity=A.class)
 private A parentA;
}
```

My question is how can I make the mapping of the field latestB in the A entity object without doing any de-normalization (not keeping in sync the field with triggers/listeners)?

Perhaps this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553429) gives some answers, but really I don't understand how it can work since I still want to be able to fetch all childs objects.

Thanks for reading/helping.

**PS:** I use hibernate as ORM/JPA provider, so an Hibernate solution can be provided if no JPA solution exists.
**PS2:** Or just tell me that I should not do this (with arguments of course) ;-)

Comment: Proprietary features allowed? If yes, what is your provider?

Comment: I use Hibernate in the back-end, but would prefer a full JPA solution. But even though if you have an Hibernate solution, then feel free to add it please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use hibernate as ORM/JPA provider, so an Hibernate solution can be provided if no JPA solution exists.

Implementing the acceptable solution (i.e. fetching a `Date` for the latest `B`) would be possible using a `@Formula`.

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany (mappedBy="parentA")
    private Collection<B> allBs;

    @Formula("(select max(b.some_date) from B b where b.a_id = id)")
    private Date latestBDate;
}
```

#### References

- Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide

  - [2.4.3.1. Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2785)

#### Resources

- [Hibernate Derived Properties - Performance and Portability](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_derived_properties_performance_and)

Comment: Will accept this answer as it is the nearest that I wanted to do, but it has the drawback to generate N+1 queries, hasn't it?

Comment: @Matthieu Yes, it has. Maybe you could use a "special" version of the entity with the `@Formula` only for the use case that needs it.

Answer (score 2):

See,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Filtering.2C_Complex_Joins

Basically JPA does not support this, but some JPA providers do.

You could also,
- Make the variable transient and lazy initialize it from the OneToMany, or just provide a get method that searches the OneToMany.
- Define another foreign key to the latest.
- Remove the relationship and just query for the latest.

Comment: Thx for helping.
> Make the variable transient and lazy initialize it from the OneToMany: what do you mean? traverse the collection?
> provide a get method that searches the OneToMany : isn't it quite an ugly solution to query the EntityManager inside an Entity object?

Also, what I would like to be able to do is to have the result in one single SQL query.